NavigationManager.NavigateTo() in Blazor web app?
I cannot get NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/servers") to work in my project. The /servers endpoint is valid with a @page "/servers".  I've tried everything and cannot get it to work.  I get an Exception of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException' was thrown.
I've tried other endpoints I know exist but keep getting NavigationException. NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/servers"); should take me to the routable servers component after clicking submit and saving my data.
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager;
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/servers");
@page "/server/{id:int}"

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager;


<h3>Edit Server</h3>
<br />
<br />

@if (server != null)
{

    <EditForm Model=server FormName="formServer" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
        <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="server.ServerId" hidden></InputNumber>
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label class="col-form-label">Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <InputText @bind-Value=server.Name></InputText>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label class="col-form-label">City</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <InputText @bind-Value=server.City></InputText>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label class="col-form-label">Online</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <InputCheckbox @bind-Value=server.IsOnline></InputCheckbox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-primary" typeof="submit">Update</button>
        &nbsp;
        <a href="/servers" class="btn btn-primary">Close</a>

    </EditForm>
}


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private Server? server { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        server ??= ServersRepository.GetServerById(this.id);
    }
    private void Submit()
    {
        if (server != null)
            ServersRepository.UpdateServer(server.ServerId, server);

        try
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/servers");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error Message: {ex.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Inner Error Message: {ex.InnerException}");

        }
    }
}

Component I'm going to:
@page "/servers"

<h3>Servers</h3>
<br />
<br />

<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row w-60">
        @foreach (var city in cities)
        {
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="@($"/images/{city}.png")" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="/server/edit" class="btn btn-primary">@city</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

<ul>
    @foreach (var server in servers)
    {
        <li>
            @server.Name in @server.City is
            <span style="color:@((server.IsOnline ? "Green" : "Red"))">
                @(server.IsOnline ? "Online" : "Offline")
                <a href="/server/@server.ServerId" class="btn btn-link">Edit</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    private List<Server> servers = ServersRepository.GetServersByCity("Toronto");
    private List<string> cities = CitiesRepository.GetCities();


}


[Polite] "Is there something wrong with NavigationManager.NavigateTo() in Blazor web app?" Probably no, but there's almost certainly something wrong with your code.  The problem is you haven't provided enough information to answer where.  NET version?   Blazor Server/WASM  Global/Per Page/Component interactivity.  Code?

Hi it's Blazor server I believe (I'm new). .NET 9.0
I'm using , clicking submit, runs c# function to update data then I try to Navigate to the servers routable component but get Navigation Exception.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis did I answer your questions?

Interactivity? Global or Per Page/Component?

Ugh..MrC..I don't know.  I'm too new to Blazor.  There is interactivity.  I believe it is per page.  Idk what i'm talking about :)

Got it figured out.
App.razor added following line:
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

Program.cs added the following 2 lines:
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();


Not sure what you are doing but here's a simplified demo based on your code that works as advertised.
Project setup => Net9.0 - Blazor Web App Template - Server - Global Interactivity.
Server
public class Server
{
    public int ServerId { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; } = "[Not Set]";
    public string Name { get; set; } = "[Not Set]";
    public bool IsOnline { get; set; }
}

Home/Server
@page "/"
@page "/Servers"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<ul>
    @foreach (var server in servers)
    {
        <li>
            @server.Name in @server.City is
            <span style="color:@((server.IsOnline ? "Green" : "Red"))">
                @(server.IsOnline ? "Online" : "Offline")
                <a href="/server/@server.ServerId" class="btn btn-link">Edit</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    List<Server> servers = new() { 
        new() { ServerId = 1, City="London", IsOnline = true, Name="Server-1" }, 
        new() { ServerId = 2, City="Paris", IsOnline = true, Name="Server-2" }
    };
}

ServerEditForm
@page "/server/{id:int}"

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager;


<h3>Edit Server</h3>

@if (server != null)
{
    <EditForm Model=server FormName="formServer" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
        <span>Hello</span>
        <div class="text-end m-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" typeof="submit">Update</button>
            <a href="/servers" class="btn btn-primary">Close</a>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
}


@code {
    [Parameter] public int id { get; set; }

    private Server? server { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Fake get a record
        server = new() { ServerId = 1, City = "London", IsOnline = true, Name = "Server-1" };
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
    private async void Submit()
    {
        // Fake save a record
        await Task.Delay(100);

        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/servers");
    }
}

The project Repo is here - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO79284001

Well MrC your code works!  I'm trying to figure out what is different between yours and mine.  Thank you so much for the help!

So, I added both of your components into my project and I got the same Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException error.  Target framework is .NET 9.0 and yours worked on .NET 9.0.  I don't know what's going on...

My best suggestion is to produce a [MRE] that demonstrates your problem.  You often figure out what you're doing wrong in the process.

I commented out everything I could and put in the fake updates into my project and still get the navigation exception...ugh  Ha!  I was typing this up before I saw your last comment.  I'll read the minimal reproducible example doc and try again.  Thank you!

The minimal program gave the same navigation exception....

Thank you MrC!!  -- how do i give you credit for pointing me in the right direction?

NP don't worry - I'm not a points seeker.  Your problem is very common - choosing the wrong template options without realising it.  Too many options without the knowledge of what they all do.

True statement...
